# Return first non NaN value in python list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

What would be the best way to return the first non nan value from this list?

```
testList = [nan, nan, 5.5, 5.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5]
```

edit:

nan is a float

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing it a lot, put it into a function to make it readable and easy:

```
import math

t = [float('nan'), float('nan'), 5.5, 5.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5]

def firstNonNan(listfloats):
  for item in listfloats:
    if math.isnan(item) == False:
      return item

firstNonNan(t)
5.5
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#next), a [generator expression](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), and [`math.isnan`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/math.html#math.isnan):

```
>>> from math import isnan
>>> testList = [float('nan'), float('nan'), 5.5, 5.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5]
>>> next(x for x in testList if not isnan(x))
5.5
>>>
```

Comment: `next(x for x in testList if x == x)` would work too, and it's probably a bit faster since it avoids a lot of lookups for the function (although pretty unreadable).

Answer (score 6):

It would be very easy if you were using NumPy:

```
array[numpy.isfinite(array)][0]
```

... returns the first finite (non-NaN and non-inf) value in the NumPy array 'array'.

Comment: Very clean and probably faster than manual looping.

Comment: I am surely not understanding something about this method, but it still seems the easiest one so I managed by creating the array of True and False value and counting whichever I need: `list(np.isfinite(array)).count(False)`

Answer (score 1):

**one line lambda below:**

```
from math import isnan
lst = [float('nan'), float('nan'), 5.5, 5.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5]

lst
[nan, nan, 5.5, 5.0, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5]
```

**first non nan value**

```
lst[lst.index(next(filter(lambda x: not isnan(x), lst)))]
5.5
```

**index of first non nan value**

```
lst.index(next(filter(lambda x: not isnan(x), lst)))
2
```