# Remove Nan occurence/s before first number in Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array (arr) with random NaNs and numbers.

```
arr = np.array((np.nan, np.nan, 2.3, np.nan, np.nan, 6.4, np.nan))
```

I need to check and remove, if present, Nan occurence/s before first number in index, here below the result:

```
result = np.array((2.3, np.nan, np.nan, 6.4, np.nan))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129495/return-first-non-nan-value-in-python-list), you can find the first non nan value, then slice your array from this index onwards. Easy to use the `numpy.where` method, similar to how they use it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432112/is-there-a-numpy-function-to-return-the-first-index-of-something-in-an-array/432289)
This should work:

`arr[np.where( np.isnan(arr)==False)[0][0]:]`

of course if you want to actually override the old array you can do:

`arr = arr[np.where( np.isnan(arr)==False)[0][0]:]`

and in the example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array((np.nan, np.nan, 2.3, np.nan, np.nan, 6.4, np.nan))
result = arr[np.where( np.isnan(arr)==False)[0][0]:]
```

has `[2.3 nan nan 6.4 nan]` in `result`

Answer (score 0):

you could also do something like:

```
import math
for i,x in enumerate(arr):
    if not math.isnan(x):
        break
arr = arr[i:]
```